# push notification and provision profile

Tags: ios-provisioning

First I've created a provision profile and created a simple small app.

Next I want to work with push-notifications and I've created push-notification sertificates. The question is – do I need to renew/recreate provision profile?

Answer (score 0):

Even though push notifications and other entitlements are configured in the AppID, provisioning profiles contain a snapshot of the AppID entitlements, so

**yes**, you do need to regenerate your provisioning profiles.